# how to change icon depend upon the Mobile no, email Id

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-forms

input field email or mobile number, if customer enter email Id need show email icon, mobile no show country code
form validation mobile number validated show span +91, email Id validate show icon but this not working..

```
    <ion-item [class.error]="!mobilenumber.valid && mobilenumber.touched" class="tog_input animated fadeInLeft delay">
             <span item-left *ngIf="mobIcon == true" class="countryCode">+91</span>
               <ion-icon name="ios-person"  *ngIf="emailIcon == true" item-left color="light" class="PreLoginIcon" ></ion-icon>
             <ion-label id="output" class="labels"  stacked floating> enter email/ mobile no</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text"  [(ngModel)]=" LoginObj.mobilenumber"  maxlength="45" formControlName="mobilenumber" ></ion-input>
            </ion-item>

    constructor() {
    this.registerForm = formBuilder.group({
      'mobilenumber': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), this.MailorNumber])],
      'Password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])]
    });
    this.mobilenumber = this.registerForm.controls['mobilenumber'];
    this.Password = this.registerForm.controls['Password'];

  }
    MailorNumber(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
        var email = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
        var mob = /(^([1-9]{1})([0-9]{9})$)/;
          if ((control.value != '') ) {
              return { MailorNumber: true };
            }
            else if (!(control.value.match(mob))){
              this.mobIcon= true;
              return { MailorNumber: true };

            }
           else if( !(control.value.match(email))){
            this.emailIcon= true;
             return { MailorNumber: true };

            }}
```

Comment: Please specify what problem you are facing and what you have tried to solve it. Otherwise it sounds like "get this task done for me".

Comment: form validation mobile number validated  show span +91, email Id validate show icon but this not working...

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic in the if statement:

```
if ((control.value != '') ) { // <-- returns true if control has value
  return { MailorNumber: true };
}
else if (!(control.value.match(mob))){ // <-- if the control has value how to evaluate this?
  this.mobIcon= true;
  return { MailorNumber: true };
}
else if( !(control.value.match(email))){ // <-- and this?
  this.emailIcon= true;
  return { MailorNumber: true };
}
```

Surely it should read something like this:

```
if (!control.value) {
  return { MailorNumber: true };
} else if (control.value.match(email)) {
  this.emailIcon = true;
  return { MailorNumber: true };
} else if (control.value.match(mob)) {
  this.mobIcon = true;
  return { MailorNumber: true };
}
```

Comment: So mobIcon is undefined. It could be a hundred different reasons why that is. In the snippet you provided there is error in your if statement, you have mixed template driven forms with model driven form, MailorNumber seems to be used as it's a custom validator but that implementation makes no sense. I recommend you provide a plunker and I am sure someone might be able to help you.